# Hdfs file list in scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

i am trying to find the list of file in hdfs directory but the code its expecting file as the input when i try to run the below code.

```
val TestPath2="hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hdfs/QERESULTS1.csv"
val hdfs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
      val hadoopPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(TestPath1)
      val recursive = true
     // val ri = hdfs.listFiles(hadoopPath, recursive)()
      //println(hdfs.getChildFileSystems)
      //hdfs.get(sc

val ri=hdfs.listFiles(hadoopPath, true)
println(ri)
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ? Can you brief the issue bit more ?

Comment: Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hdfs/QERESULTS1.csv, expected: file:///
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:642)

Comment: i am trying to find the list of files in hdfs directory using scala

Answer (score 2):

You should set your default filesystem to **hdfs://** first, I seems like your default filesystem is **file://**

```
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration 
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://some-path")

val hdfs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf)

...
```